# How to I fix this visual studio bug for my c++ program?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, g++

I have written this program in C++ and when I run it in visual studio my output is:

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\Me\OneDrive\Desktop\c++\" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "c:\Users\Me\OneDrive\Desktop\c++\"main
Access is denied.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.636 seconds
```

The 'cout' does work when I output an integer and floats, it seems it just wont output strings but the printf function does. How do I solve this>?

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {


    cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure Visual Studio does not use g++. Do you perhaps use Visual Studio Code? Also "Access is denied." is an error unrelated to your code, maybe you tried to compile while the program was still running.

Comment: *"Access is denied."* You fail to create executable, possibly because last executable is still running.

Comment: The presence of the message "Access is denied." can't possibly depend on the type of the value you're outputting. You're almost certainly misdiagnosing the issue.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is not your code, or `cout`, or a Visual Studio bug.

The problem is that, as shown in your console output, "access [was] denied" when creating your new executable. You're not even *running* you're new code!

Most likely you have a previous instance of your application still open, probably waiting for you to "press any key to continue…". The executable cannot be replaced with a new one while it's running.

Find the window and end the program. Then you'll be able to build your new version.

Comment: Someone is downvoting every single one of my answers, regardless of merit, and it's extremely tiresome.

Answer (score -3):

Access is denied may be a permission issue. Ensure you have permission to run in the directory you are in and the compiled code can output libs correctly.

In the folder this class is in, right click and go to security and add your account with read and write access.

Let me know if this works for your environment. Do feel free to elaborate on your G++ reference however. The code below compiles and has no real difference to your approach.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
        cout << "Hello, World!";
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: this is exact same code as OPs without the `endl`, no?

Comment: this is not an answer. Comments are to ask for clarification. If the question is too unclear to be answered, then better dont answer

Comment: @idclev463035818 No, it's also formatted worse than the original ;)

Comment: btw answers along the line of "try this [...], maybe it works" generally do not really fit well into the SO format. This isnt a forum where typically there is a dialogue between question and answers, but instead an answer should be selfcontained, without further need for clarification

Comment: well updated, but it is still not clear what is the relevance of the code. If you think removing `endl` will fix the issue then you should explain why

Comment: Difficult open ended questions, with obscure error messages that have potentially hundreds of solutions require a dialogue or numerous answers for people to try